# How do I view headers, and message source in Hotmail

Tags: email, smtp, outlook, tls, smtp-headers

Hotmail changed their interface, and now I can't right click on the message (in list view) and view headers. Also I can't see the page source, besides the clutter within the regular HTML markup.

Can anyone tell me:

- How to get the message headers
- How to view the message source
- Where I need to complain if neither of the options above have an "ideal" solution

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ would be a better home for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message headers are located in a small sub menu (a small downwards arrow) besides the word "Reply".

You can find the message source from the headers.